# Angular's ng-view routing not displaying (injector modulerr error)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I seem to be having an issue with Angular routing.  My current index.html file is only displaying the header div that is in the index.html file but not the ng-view aspect of the code which should display a new page located at views/login.html.

```js
var app = angular.module('Bandit', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', 'locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
 $routeProvider

        //login feedback page
        .when('/feedback', {
            templateUrl: 'views/loginfeedback.html',
            controller: 'loginFeedbackController'
        })


        // home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        })

        //Catch all
        .otherwise({ 
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ENG">



 <head>

  <title>Band-it</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!--Imported Style-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!--Custome Stylesheets-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/universal.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">

    <!--Imported JS Libraries-->
     <script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!--Custom-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/appRoutes.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/loginController.js"></script>

 </head>




 <body ng-app="Bandit">
  <div class='header'>
   <h1 id='symbol'>B</h1>
  </div>


  <!--Angular Dynamic View-->
  <div ng-view></div>


 </body>
</html>
```

The error message from the console that I am getting is:

angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] [http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=Bandit&p1=Error%3A%…Fbandit%2FBanditMask%2Fpublic%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A222][1](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=Bandit&p1=Error%3A%25%E2%80%A6Fbandit%2FBanditMask%2Fpublic%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A222)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use `$locationProvider` instead of using `locationProvider` in `app.config`. and not sure please share the link.